# Display Resolution Reverts to Low Resolution After Each Re-Boot

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr, intel-nuc

I have an Intel NUC (NUC5PPYH)running Xubuntu 15.10, and MythBuntu Frontend.  The system uses a 42 inch Samgung LED TV as the display device.  The NUC is using it's on-board Intel Graphics Chipset (driver=i915).

When the NUC was first installed in mid 2015, I set the display resolution to 1920 x 1080, and everything worked well for some months, with the display always remaining at 1920 x 1080 after every re-boot.

Recently, I have found that when the NUC is rebooted, the resolution reverts to 1360 x 768, and I have to manually reset the display resolution to 1920 x 1080.  The display resolution then remains correctly set, but only until such time as the NUC is again rebooted, at which time the display reverts to 1360 x 768.

Can anyone advise why the display resolution would be reverting to 1360 x 768 after every reboot, and what needs to be done to make the display stay at 1920 x 1080 ?

Edited:  9 Jan 2016 - `xrandr` output as requested:

```
royg@royg-desktop:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1360x768      60.02 +
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
royg@royg-desktop:~$
```

Thanks,

RoyG

Comment: Please paste the output of the `xrandr`command in your question

Comment: xrandr output added to the original post as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Create a startup script that runs an `xrandr` command that sets your resolution.

That way, every time you login `RandR` will set your preferred resolution for you automatically.

Create a script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output monitor_name --mode 1920x1080
```

Save it with a `.sh` postfix.
You can find out your monitor name with `xrandr | grep "connected"`.

Search for "startup applications" in the dash and add the above script as a startup program - make sure you've made the script executable.

Should work now **=)**